# openerp7 - Return tree view from class with no new fields

Tags: treeview, openerp-7

I'm new to OpenERP 7, what is the correct way to return a tree view? How can i return the data i obtained from my function?
Here's my class code:

```
class albaranes_fallidos(osv.osv):
_name = 'albaranes_fallidos'
_inherit = 'stock.picking'
_columns = {}

def find(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    stock_picking       = self.pool.get('stock.picking')
    exist_state         = stock_picking.search(cr, uid, [('state','=','confirmed'),('origin','ilike','SO')])
    ###
    exist_lines         = stock_picking.browse(cr, uid, exist_state, context)
    ###
    exist_IN            = stock_picking.search(cr, uid, [('type','=','in'),('origin','ilike',':SO')])

    for SO in exist_lines:
        exist_PO            = stock_picking.browse(cr, uid, exist_IN, context)
        for POSO in exist_PO:
            if SO.origin in POSO.origin:
                _logger.info(POSO.origin)
                break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a domain to specify which record to load in tree view:

```
return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'name': _('Stock picking'),
        'res_model': 'stock.picking',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'tree,form',
        'target': 'current',
        'domain': [('id', 'in', exist_IN)]
    }
```